# Relative importing of modules trigger an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I have the following structure:

```
top\
    comp\
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
    base.py
    __init__.py
```

In **base.py** if I try:

```
from .comp import file1
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.components'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Why ?

Comment: Would "from comp import file1" do what you want?

Comment: Actually I noticed that if I go into the parent directory of "top" and then from there do "from top import base", your code works.

Comment: @Bemmu "from comp import file1" it works in new versions of Python, because it creates a Namespace, but this is not a relative import. I don't understand why do "from top import base" , I want to import a module file1 in base.py relative

Comment: OK, I don't understand relative imports yet, maybe someone else can help.